# Fixed Background-attachment IE issue

Tags: css

I have recently attempted to put a fixed gradient background on my website and works fine in chrome and firefox, but older versions of IE do not like it...It seems to not even let me scroll at all..was wondering if anybody could help?

```
html,body,footer,#Top,#Bottom {height: 100%}
body,footer,#Top,#Bottom   {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#d4d4d4, endColorstr=#fefefe);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top -90deg, #d4d4d4, #fefefe);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#d4d4d4), to(#fefefe));
background-image: linear-gradient(#d4d4d4, #fefefe);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#d4d4d4, #fefefe); 
}
```